# Failed to write all bytes for _bisect.so

Tags: docker, docker-compose, diskspace

I was restoring a MongoDB environment, then it failed for no space in disk.
After that I cannot execute any docker-compose command, in each attempt this error message is displayed:
Failed to write all bytes for _bisect.so

I found some references about to free space in /tmp, although I want to be sure that was the best alternative of solution.

Comment: Can you add a df output ?

Comment: did you manage to get it working? I'm facing the same issue, now that i have clean up disk space...

Answer (score 12):

Remove the docker images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)
```

**UPDATE:**

you can now use prune

```
docker system prune -af
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Answer (score 1):

check df
normally you will find 100% for /var/lib/docker and 100% for/ 
try to free some space, may be stop syslog service.

Then remove and restart your containers

recheck df
now /var/lib/docker should be around 15%

Answer (score 1):

During a `docker-compose` command, I got a similar error ("Failed to write all bytes for _ctypes.pyd") because my drive had no space left on it.